# Вывод netstat -anp

Tags: linux, bash

Когда ввожу netstat -anp | grep LISTEN часть ip адресов выводится в виде 0.0.0.0:80,  а часть в виде :::8081. В чем разница? Или 0.0.0.0:8081 тоже самое, что и ::::8081?

Comment: `::::8081` это тоже самое, что `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:8081`. Это IPv6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Адрес `0.0.0.0` означает, что программа прослушивает порт на всех IPv**4**-адресах данного компьютера (т.е. на всех сетевых интерфейсах). Прослушивание может быть также только на конкретных адресах. Например, `192.168.0.1` или `1.2.3.4`. Есть специальная группа адресов - от `127.0.0.1` до `127.255.255.255` (подсеть `127.0.0.0/8`). Это так называемый *loopback*-адрес, доступный только в пределах локальной машины. Подключиться к нему с другого компьютера невозможно.

Адрес `::` (вместе с портом он имеет вид, например, `:::80`) означает, что программа слушает порт на всех IPv**6**-адресах компьютера. Поскольку IPv6 гораздо более длинный, были введены правила его сокращённой записи и данный адрес на самом деле имеет вид `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` (8 блоков по два байта, т.е. четыре шестнадцатиричных цифры). Здесь тоже есть `loopback`. Это адрес `::1` (точнее, подсеть `::1/128`).

Кстати, прослушиваемые порты для протокола TCP можно посмотреть командой `netstat -tnl`, для UDP - `netstat -unl`.